# Feature Engineer each class separately in Binary Classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, f1score

I have an imbalanced tabular dataset, my problem is a binary classification. The dataset is strongly imbalanced so I have performed oversampling, but it did not solve the issue, you can find the Classification Report below:(The accuracy is 88% but I don't care, it does not represent well the performance since the dataset is imbalanced)
[image]
The only explanation that I found is that the features selected are well suited to detect "0" while they don't tell much information about the "1" class, is there any way to catch the best features that represent the "1" class, maybe split the dataset into 1_Class_Dataset and 0_Class_Dataset and catch the best features for each and then combine both? If it is not possible can you please suggest another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Engineering separate features for the different classes is not a viable approach.

When you got to use your model, you do not know the class to which your measurements belongs. Consequently, you do not know which features to engineer.

However, good statistical methods see minimal problems with imbalance. I will post my usual links that I give to questions about class imbalance.

[Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466), a useful Stack Exchange post

[Damage Caused by Classification Accuracy and Other Discontinuous Improper Accuracy Scoring Rules](https://fharrell.com/post/class-damage), a blog post by Frank Harrell, founding chair of the Department of Biostatistics at Vanderbilt University

[Classification vs. Prediction](https://fharrell.com/post/classification), another blog post by Frank Harrell

[Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274), another Stack Exchange post

[Proper scoring rule when there is a decision to make (e.g. spam vs ham email)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636), another Stack Exchange post

[Why is it that if you undersample or oversample you have to calibrate your output probabilities?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/558942), another Stack Exchange post

[A tweet by Frank Harrell](https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en)